# Encrypted Private key in JAVA: java.security.InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, security, private-key, pkcs#8

Hi I am trying to read Encrypted Private key in JAVA. The Key is being used is PKCS# 8 with Encryption Algo as PBE with SHA-1 and 2 key DESede.

The code as given below:

```
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo("RSA",readFileBytes(filename));
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("pwd".toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDESede");
Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey,algParams);
KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
```

And i am facing the below mentioned error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEKey
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:888)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1507)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1438)
at com.abc.utils.CertificateUtil.readEncryptedPrivateKey(CertificateUtil.java:62)
at com.abc.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:16)
```

Comment: Why do you think `Cipher.getInstance("1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.4")` should not throw that exception? Ciphers are called things like `AES`. `Blowfish`, `DES`, `DESede`, `PBEWithSHA1AndDESede`, `RC2`, `RSA`, ...

Answer (score 2):

```
SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA1AndDESede")
```

`PBEWithSHA1AndDESede` is not the name of a cipher algorithm supported by Java. For the correct list, see [Standard Algorithm Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher).

Possibly you meant `PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede`?